# How can I structure my C++ code so that I only write my common methods once?

Tags: c++, winforms, class, inheritance, managed

If C++.NET allowed multiple inheritance, I would have my common methods in a class and derive from it.

I have classes derived from Panel, Label, TabControl ... which have the same methods exactly.

How can I structure my C++ code so that I only write my common methods once?

Here is a simple example of a property I want to add to each derived class.  Extension methods sound ideal, but don't exist in C++.

```
private: int panelBottomMargin;
public:
    [Browsable(true)]
    [CategoryAttribute("Layout"), DescriptionAttribute(
        "Specify the gap between the last control and the bottom of the panel"),
    DefaultValueAttribute(panelBottomMarginDefault)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility::Visible)]
    property int PanelBottomMargin
    {
        int get() { return this->panelBottomMargin; }
        void set(int margin) { this->panelBottomMargin = margin; }
    }
```

Comment: Create extension methods for the _control_ class?

Comment: @Stormenet Your comment sounds promising, can you point me at something more specific?

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't see that the programming language is c++. But if you like to know more about c# extension methods, have look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: As far as I can tell C++ does not support extension methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't quite make out for sure what you mean by "common methods" here, but generally speaking namespace level non-member functions are the best way to do that (see pretty much every algorithm in the standard library).

If it actually needs access to private attributes of your class then it's probably not a common method and should be implemented in the level of inheritance where the attribute it operates on exist.

It's almost certainly an abuse of inheritance to put common methods into a class that you then inherit from: Use inheritance to extend, NOT to reuse.

Comment: I certainly do not want to abuse inheritance, I just want to extend each derived class in the same way.  I've edited the question to add an example property which I want to add to each derived class.  Sorry, it's properties as well as methods.  I just want to do it once, not once for each derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Put your common methods in a Utility class, create an instance of this class (pass the object to work on to the constructor) when needed.

Comment: I'd need to have the same, or very similar, code in every derived class.  I didn't want any duplication at all if possible.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with static methods? Or instantiating a new class which can operate on objects of the type given? Its best to not abuse inheritance in ways which clearly don't follow the "is-a" doctrine - use "has-a" whenever possible.

Generally, if MI is being considered as a solution to your problem which does not involve "mixin" type semantics, you should consider a new solution.

Comment: Well, mixins are not supported by .NET at the moment anyway, right?

Comment: Whilst I support "has-a" being preferable to "is-a", there's nothing inherently wrong with MI at all. What you're thinking of is `virtual` inheritance from C++, which is different.

Comment: I'd need to have the same, or very similar, code in every derived class. I didn't want any duplication at all if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use .NETs "[extension methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benwilli/archive/2008/12/03/net-extension-methods-from-c.aspx)" if you don't need to access private/protected fields of an object.

Comment: As far as I can tell C++ does not support extension methods.

Comment: @bobinski AFAIK you can't declare/implement extension methods in c++/.net. But you can call existing ones. In that way you write your extensions once in C# and use them in both languages. BTW VB.net should work too.

Comment: @bobinski and yes, that does not look as nice in c++/.net as it looks in _natural_ .net languages.

Comment: @bobinski Ok, if you don't know C# yet, there is no need either. It only pays off if you actually use both languages in different projects.